# Jquery .show() implementation with css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to Javascript so this may be simple but please direct me. The following code is on jquery's documentation http://api.jquery.com/show/

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>

     <button>Show it</button>
      <p style="display: none">Hello  2</p>

     <script>
     $( "button" ).click(function() {
      $( "p" ).show( "slow" );
     });
    </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

My question is why can I NOT change "p" to a class if I want an entire content region to appear on click. A good example is seen at www.shopify.com under the header.

I am thinking something like this

```
<div class="first-reveal">
 <p style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

<script>
 $( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "first-reveal" ).show( "fast" );
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Should be `$( ".first-reveal" ).show( "fast" );` - the dot is your 'class' indicator.  Really, should be `$('.first-reveal p').show('fast');` - because it's your `p` that's hidden, so need to select *that* element.

Comment: And you *can* change it to a class: `$('p').addClass('my_new_class');`

Answer (score 1):

you try to select a class you have to do it like

```
 $( "button" ).click(function() {
     $( ".first-reveal" ).show( "fast" );
 });
```

class selector is `.` and id selector is `#`

e.g.

```
$(".myClass")

$("#myId")
```

same as in css :)

Comment: @user3773116 Also, you'll want to set `display:none` on the `<div>` rather than the `<p>`.

Comment: Wow so simple. Thanks guys. Awesome. Any suggestion for best practice in handling 3 different div's like on shopify. When I use commas it does the first but not second or third.

Answer (score 0):

`first-reveal` is a class, therefore, with jQuery, we need to add a fullstop to the beginning of the selector, like so:

```
$( ".first-reveal" ).show( "fast" );
```

Although, if it were an ID, not a class, we would do the following:

```
$( "#first-reveal" ).show( "fast" );
```